# ¿Cómo implementar un CRON en PHP para enviar Correos?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, trigger, cron

Necesito Enviar mensualmente (el primer día de cada mes), un correo **automáticamente** a los usuarios de una tabla.
Estoy trabajando con la estructura **POO** bajo el patrón **MVC** y **MySQL** con phpmyadmin.
Tengo una **clase Usuarios** en el controlador Usuarios donde puedo acceder al los datos de la tabla de usuarios a los que necesito enviarles el correo, ¿Cómo y dónde puedo crear el **CRON**?

(Si hace falta subir pantallazos, me avisan de qué entidad por favor)

Comment: Bajo qué Sistema Operativo estás trabajando?, tienes acceso al servidor por consola, escritorio remoto u otra forma?, ya tienes hecho tu script que envía correos?

Comment: Estoy en Windows en éste momento, he accedido al servidor vía FTP; no tengo hecho mi script aún... es primera vez que veo **cron**. 
Me enseñas porfa?

Comment: @Vlady Qué datos se requiere para acceder por consola?... he visto algo relativo a: "`ssh nombredelusuario@ipdetuserverenelehosting`" pero no sé si es el nombre de usuario del hosting o de mi pc..

Comment: Se necesita saber el SO del hosting, no de tu equipo, si me confirmas que es Windows te explico así, para acceder por consola es `ssh` como indicas (si tu hosting te lo permite), el nombre de usuario se refiere al usuario del servidor, necesitas que tu script funcione como quieres ejecutando el comando `php script.php` en una terminal

Comment: Los crones son de servidor y son ajenos al lenguaje de tu aplicación, es decir, pueden ejecutar cualquier tipo de script (no sólo PHP); edita tu pregunta con todo la info que te pedí.

Comment: Ah ok. El SO es Linux,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes tu script llamado `envioCorreos.php` y alojado en `/home/candelo/scripts/` lo que tienes que hacer es:

- Abrir el editor de texto con el crontab de tu SO

```
crontab -e
```

- Determinar la frecuencia con la que se ejecutará tu cron con el orden:

```
minuto   hora   día_del_mes   mes   día_de_la_semana
```

- Agregar el comando que se va a ejecutar, en este caso un script php:

```
php /ruta/al/archivo.php
```

Por ejemplo, si quiero que el script mencionado se ejecute cada día a media noche, en el archivo crontab agrego una línea con:

```
0 0 * * * php /home/candelo/scripts/envioCorreos.php
```

O si quiero que se ejecute una vez a la semana los lunes a las 0 horas:

```
0 0 * * 1 php /home/candelo/scripts/envioCorreos.php
```

Quizás el envío de correos es un sistema de notificaciones y quiero que se ejecuten cada 15 minutos:

```
*/15 * * * * php /home/candelo/scripts/envioCorreos.php
```

Todo depende de tus necesidades.

Más info https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_(Unix)

Comment: Mil gracias @Vlady, un abrazo grande!